# Python - is there a smart way to plus 1 between certain indexes of array?

Tags: python

I have billions of array data and I have to do `+=1` between specific indexes. Also this could be done multiple times.

This is basic routine for this job. But it's not nice way.
Can you please suggest some fancy way?

```
billions_of_records = []

for idx in indexes:
    start = some_func(idx)
    end = some_func(idx)
    for i in range(start, end, 1):
        billions_of_records[i] += 1
```

**EDIT**

I'm asking it in performance POV.

Comment: Are you allowed to use external libraries like numpy? You can do things more efficiently with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution using `numpy`. This makes use of vectorization, which reduce execution time.

```
import numpy as np

#making your records a numpy array
billions_of_records = np.array([...])

for idx in indexes:
    start = some_func(idx)
    end = some_func(idx)
    billions_of_records[start:end] += np.ones(end-start, dtype=int)
```

[numpy ones](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) returns an array of 1, which can be directly added to your records.
Note the `dtype` argument in `np.ones`, it should be the same of `billions_of_records`. That is, use `int` if your records are integers. If they are floats, pass `float` or don't pass it at all, since default `dtype` value is `float` (`numpy.float64` to be accurate).

Comment: Thank you Valentino. If I can install numpy package I'll try this approach.

Comment: you can install [numpy](https://numpy.org/) with `pip`. It is open source. If you are going to use a lot of math in your python programs, you'll find it very useful.